# How to have a hexagon shape tile grid map with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the last week's `TidyTuesday` challenge, I was trying to replicate a world tile grid map made in R, which can be accessible from [here](https://www.maartenlambrechts.com/2017/10/22/tutorial-a-worldtilegrid-with-ggplot2.html). Here is the code so far;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidytuesdayR)
library(highcharter)
library(maps)
library(jsonlite) # Load the 'jsonlite' package
library(showtext)
library(showtextdb)
library(ggtext)


world_grid <- read_csv("worldtilegrid.txt")
tt <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load('2023-05-30')
tt <- tt$centenarians 
countries_count <- tt %>%
  group_by(place_of_death_or_residence) %>%
  mutate(place_of_death_or_residence = case_when(place_of_death_or_residence == "France (French Guiana)" ~ "France",
                                                 place_of_death_or_residence == "France (Martinique)" ~ "France",
                                                 place_of_death_or_residence == "France (Saint Barthélemy)" ~ "France",
                                                 place_of_death_or_residence == "United States" ~ "United States of America",
                                                 place_of_death_or_residence == "United Kingdom" ~ "Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
                                                 place_of_death_or_residence == "Puerto Rico" ~ "United States of America",
                                                 TRUE ~ place_of_death_or_residence)) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  as.data.frame()
  
data_to_plot <- world_grid %>%
  left_join(countries_count, by = c("name" = "place_of_death_or_residence")) %>%
  # mutate(count = replace_na(count, 0))

plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = data_to_plot, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = count), color = "#ffffff") +
  geom_text(data = data_to_plot, aes(x = x, y = y, label = alpha.2), color = "#ffffff", alpha = 0.5, family = "caption", size = 25) +
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = "gray", low = "#7F3C8D", high = "#80BA5A", guide = "colorbar") +
  theme_void() +
  labs(fill = "Count",
       title = "Verified Oldest People Around the World",
       subtitle = "This map demonstrates the distribution of the place of birth or residence<br>of the verified 100 oldest people across countries.") +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown(size = 110, hjust = 0.5, family = "plottitle", linewidth = 0.1),
        plot.subtitle = element_markdown(size = 80, hjust = 0.5, family = "title", lineheight = 0.2),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#dedad2", color = NA),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_markdown(size = 65, family = "caption", vjust = 0.75),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 40, family = "caption"),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.2))
```

This code produces this map

[image]

Now, what I want to do is achieving a hexagon shaped geom_tile instead of instead of the ones in the shared screenshot. How can I do that? Thank you for your suggestions beforehand.

Comment: The problem is that squares and hexagons tile differently. It would be possible to have a hexagonal equivalent, but you would need to know the specific co-ordinates of the hexagons (it is not a one-for-one swap). You can see an example [here](https://public.tableau.com/static/images/We/Week44Thecountrieswiththemostbankholidays_1/multi-colourHEX/1.png)

Comment: In the given example I mentioned above along with attaching the link, the coordinates are given for the geom_tile as point coordinates. Based on that, can I produce a hexagonal equivalent, or do I still something else?

Comment: that's my point: squares and hexagons don't tile the same way. Each row on a hexagonal grid is offset by half-a-hexagon compared to the row above, compared to a square tiling. Each row is only half a hexagon lower than the row above. Each hexagon has six faces to join to adjacent countries rather than 4. The locations of the centre of the hexagons is thus different from the locations of the centres of the squares. You _could_ just turn the squares into hexagons, but then they wouldn't tile properly. They would just be hexagonal points.

Comment: There's a blog post here: https://www.simoncoulombe.com/2018/01/unvotes_hexgrid/ highlighting one way of doing this (doesn't always force countries in the same continent to be close to each other, unfortunately)